# Is there a more resilient alternative to GdkPixbuf for getting pixbufs in Gtk?

Tags: gtk, gdk, gdkpixbuf

I've been using GdkPixbuf for displaying downloaded images in a program, which works well, but occasionally encounter JPEGs with non-fatal corruption (eg. "Application transferred too few scanlines") that GdkPixbuf can't handle. I can usually confirm these *are* corrupted in some way with `jpeginfo` but any number of other Gtk programs like Gimp and Eye of Gnome handle them without error or warning.

Is there an alternative to GdkPixbuf I can use in standard GLib/Gtk to generate pixbufs or a way to disable choking on non-fatal corruption errors?